# How to replace a part of a string with another part?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have long String like `KA01F332-9:25,KA01F212-9:27,KA01F242-9:35,KA01F232-9:45,`. These are combination of vehicle no and time. now I want to replace the time of `KA01F242` to `10:20` How can I do this.

So far I hav done this.

```
String busEAT=KA01F332-9:25,KA01F212-9:27,KA01F242-9:35,KA01F232-9:45,;
busEAT.subString(busEAT.indexOf(vno),busEAT.indexOf(','));
```

but I am not getting the exact value .and it has to be done dynamically can any one help me in this.

Comment: try this --  str = str.replace(str.substring(str.indexOf("KA01F242")+9,str.indexOf("KA01F242")+13),"10:20");

Comment: @amitbhardwaj Thanks for ur reply, here `+9` and `+13` dont work for me. I want it has to be dynamic, so num might be vary . .

Comment: try this -----    String string= str.substring(str.indexOf("KA01F242")+9,str.length());
        string = string.replace(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(",")), "10:20");
        str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("KA01F242")+9);
        str = str+string;

Comment: here + 9 is for `KA01F242-` and this is fixed according to your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex like this :

```
    String s = "KA01F332-9:25,KA01F212-9:27,KA01F242-9:35,KA01F232-9:45,";
    System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("(?<=KA01F242-).*?(?=,)", "10:20")); 
   // Positive look-behind for "KA01F242" and positive look-ahead for "," . They are just matched but not captured, so they will not get replaced.
```

O/P:

```
KA01F332-9:25,KA01F212-9:27,KA01F242-10:20,KA01F232-9:45,
```

EDIT :

`"(?<=KA01F242-).*?(?=,)", "10:20")` --> First looks for any character preceeded by "KA01F242" (positive look-behind), then it selects all the characters ("KA01F242" is just matched, not selected.) Next, all the successive characters are selected until you get a comma (which is agin matched, not selected)